# How do you clear someone's inventory upon spawn?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to start a server that clears your inventory when spawning without pressure plates. Please help.

Comment: Shouldn't players spawn with empty inventories anyway? Do I misunderstand something?

Comment: The only way to *not* have the player's inventory cleared would be to use `/gamerule keepInventory`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command `/clear [targets] [item] [maxCount]`, where:

- **targets** is optional. It is the name of the player (or a target selector) whose inventory you wish to clear. If no player is
  specified, it will default to the player running the command.
- **item** is optional. It is the item to clear (See list of Minecraft items). If no item is specified, then all items in the player's
  inventory will be cleared.
- **maxCount** is optional. It is the maximum number of items that will be cleared. If you omit this parameter or use -1, all matching items
  will be cleared.

For your requirements, I suggest `/clear @p`, on a command block [looping](https://www.digminecraft.com/command_blocks/make_repeating_command_block.php) right bellow the player.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. First I need to know:

- Do you want to make a PVP server or a freebuild server or something else?
- In which cases do you want to clear the player's inventory?
- Which version and console do you use?

What you can do is set the spawnpoint into a cube on bedrock, somewhere near to y=5 or so, and then clear the inventory of every player which is in the cube, and finally, teleport these players to the real spawn.

Answer (score 0):

the best way that I can think of is to make  a command where every player except certain players have a repeat command the clears their inventory like this:

`/clear @a[name=!NAME,name=!NAME,name=!NAME]`

replace the extra name with names of players that you want their items to not be removed for example

`/clear @a[name=!Steve,name=!NoobSlayer700,name=!Steve(1),name=!Dinnerbone]`

this will clear all player inventories except Steve,NoobSlayer700,Steve(1) and Dinnerbone

Answer (score -1):

I only know of a method for computer and mobile.
On computer press T and type: /gamerule keepinventory false. The only thing is, on a Server, you might need to use command blocks. To do this use the command: /give (YOURUSERNAME) minecraft:command_block, enter the first command into the command block, and set the command block to always active from within the command Block and you should be good to go.
On mobile: pause the game, go into settings, and then game. Scroll down until you see the word: Cheats. Scroll a little further until you see: Keep Inventory and toggle the switch right until it is to the right.